# Encoding for downloaded files in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a controller which will sent to client a CSV file, and I created the next controller:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity downloadCsvAllInvoiceTransactionsByFilter(
        @PageableDefault(direction = DESC, sort = "invoiceDate", size = 30) Pageable pageRequest) throws IOException {
    String someVariable = "Some text";
    byte[] out = someVariable.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    LOGGER.info(new String(out));
    responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=transactions.csv" );
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type","text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(out,responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Logger is displaying the correct string:

> Some text

but in downloaded file there is another one

> U29tZSB0ZXh0

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Body of `ResponseEntity` goes through a message converter before it gets sent. The choice of the particular converter depends on class of the body and response and request headers.

I tried to reproduce the issue with your code snippet and got expected text in csv file. So I assume that you got a message converter registered that converts byte arrays the way you observe.

You can debug `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor#writeWithMessageConverters` and see which converter is chosen and why.